# Прямая речь или нет? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, цитирование

Как расставить знаки препинания? Нужно ли оформлять как прямую речь?

> Как говорил Суворов, нужно воевать не числом, а умением.

Answer (score 1):

**Как говорил Суворов, нужно "воевать не числом, а умением".**

*Как говорил Суворов* — вводное предложение (в этом случае двоеточие не ставится); в кавычки заключается только собственно крылатая фраза — "воевать не числом, а умением".

Цитатами называются дословные (точные) выдержки **из высказываний** и сочинений кого-либо, приводимые для подтверждения или пояснения своих мыслей.
В данном предложении цитирование произведено при помощи косвенной речи — цитата введена в авторскую речь вводным предложением.
(Сравните: *По мнению Я. А. Добролюбова, Печорину «не нужно подбирать слова и блистать мишурным знанием: и без этого язык у него как бритва».*)

С прямой речью предложение может быть таким.
Суворов говорил так: "Воевать не числом, а умением".

Оформление цитат (с прямой и косвенной речью) можно посмотреть здесь.
[Известные высказывания и крылатые выражения Суворова](https://autogear.ru/article/257/606/izvestnyie-vyiskazyivaniya-suvorov-ob-armii-soldatah-taktike/)

Answer (score 0):

*Как говорил Суворов, **"воюют не числом, а уменьем".***

Это встроенная в предложение цитата, причем в кавычки нужно заключать  дословное выражение.

А дословное выражение имеет такой вид:

**Воюют не числом, а уменьем!!!** Где меньше войска, там больше храбрых... В бою надо стремитца к единой главной точке и забывать о ретираде. Быстрота и внезапность заменяют число. Натиски и удары решают битву... Удивить — значит победить!

http://militera.lib.ru/science/0/pdf/sb_strategy_of_spirit.pdf

Comment: Мне кажется, что все-таки нужно кавычить _воевать не числом, а умением._ Ведь именно в таком виде высказывание считается фразеологизмом (крылатым выражением). И именно в таком виде изображено на медали _Александр Суворов._ http://server.armygoods.ru/catalog/21_medali/2119_medali_istoricheskie_lichnosti/189308/

Comment: 1) Как-то странно делить составное глагольное сказуемое (единую грамматическую конструкцию) кавычками на части. 2) Поэтому я решила поискать первоисточник. 3) Если обращаться к словам Суворова, то его лучше цитировать  дословно. 4) Фразеологизм встречается в разном виде, в том числе и с глаголом «воюют». Получается, что его глагольная часть в достаточной мере свободная. 5) Суворов ведь текст медали не редактировал.