# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом «да»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

*"Остается одна надежда на Бога да на мужество и на самоотвержение моих войск".*

В каких-то источниках есть запятая перед "да", в каких-то нет. Однозначный ответ из статей и учебников не смогла получить. Так всё же, нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 4):

С одной стороны, отсутствие запятой перед союзом ***да*** объясняется следующим правилом.

[**Однородные члены предложения, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=65) (Розенталь, § 12)

> Между однородными членами предложения, связанными одиночными соединительными союзами ***и***, ***да*** (в значении ***‘и’***), ***да и***, запятая не ставится.

С другой стороны, союз ***да*** может быть [присоединительным](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=64]]) (Розенталь, § 24), вводящим дополнительные сведения, замечания. В таком случае перед союзом образуется интонационная пауза и запятая ставится. То есть мы можем прочитать предложение, как говорится, на одном дыхании, а можем сделать ударение на ***Бога*** и "призадуматься"... Кто его знает, как эту фразу произносил Суворов. Отсюда, как мне кажется, и идут разночтения в пунктуации этого предложения.

В большинстве источников, попавшихся мне, запятая присутствует. Этот вариант выглядит более читабельным, что ли, поскольку однородные члены ***мужество*** и ***самоотвержение*** логически более тесно связаны друг с другом. Плюс некоторое нагромождение из союзов и повторяющихся предлогов ***на***.

**Дополнение**

Не знаю, как правильно поступить. Комментарий Alex_ander обозначает те мысли, которые я подразумевал, но не высказал. Стоит ли пересказывать недвусмысленно сформулированное мнение? С подачи Риммы Михайловой цитирую данный комментарий:

> Этому [постановке запятой] способствует распространённость присоединяемого; две его части, объединённые через "и", изменяют интонацию так, что союз "да" воспринимается как "***ну и ещё*** (второе и третье)". При том, что поначалу названа **одна** надежда (Бог), а не две и не три, остальное сказано как бы вдогонку, в качестве дополнения.

Comment: Я тоже склонен видеть здесь _присоединительное_ значение союза "да" (запятую поставил бы). Этому способствует распространённость присоединяемого; две его части, объединённые через "и", изменяют интонацию так, что союз "да" воспринимается как "_**ну и ещё** (второе и третье)_". При том, что поначалу названа **одна** надежда (Бог), а не две и не три, остальное сказано как бы вдогонку, в качестве дополнения.

Comment: @Alex_ander  Спасибо! Стало еще понятнее.

Comment: Мнение и разъяснения _Alex_anderа_ мне представляются правильными. Если Вы тоже их придерживаетесь, то надо это обозначить в своем ответе (конкретное решение). Я тогда с удовольствием Вас поддержу (потому что я бы тоже поставила запятую).

Comment: Ну-у... Зачем же так прямолинейно? (Я про дополнение.) Достаточно было написать так: В большинстве источников, попавшихся мне, запятая присутствует. Я тоже считаю, что она должна быть.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Улыбаюсь, спасибо! Не знаю... Стараюсь быть как можно корректнее... Не знаю...

Comment: Да все неплохо, все у Вас получается. А по поводу цитирования Суворова был на сайте еще один спорный вопрос. Если интересно, посмотрите: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452974/%d0%9f%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-3/452979#452979

Answer (score 1):

Дорогая Алина!

В приведенном Вами примере не приходится применять "с одной стороны - с другой стороны". У Вас одиночное "да" в значении "и".

[«Остается одна надежда на Бога да на мужество и самоотверженность наших войск. Спасите честь России и ее государя!»](https://fligel-rota.ru/library/books/suvorov-russkiy-bog-voyni/)

Погуглила... Предложение - не точная цитата, её передают современники кто как запомнил. Остальное - на совести корректора.

[В конце речи Суворов заключил:](http://kids.azovlib.ru/index.php/2-uncategorised/1040-suvorov-aleksandr)

> «Теперь мы среди гор, окружены неприятелем, превосходным в силах. Что
>   принять нам? Идти назад — постыдно; никогда еще не отступал я. Идти
>   вперед, к Швицу — невозможно: у Массены свыше шестидесяти тысяч, у нас
>   же нет и двадцати. К тому же мы без провианта, без патронов, без
>   артиллерии. Помощи нам ждать не от кого... Мы на краю гибели... ***Одна
>   остается надежда: на Бога да на храбрость и самоотвержение моих войск.***
>   Мы русские!»

Comment: Галина, здравствуйте!  Мы, наверно, не можем сказать точно, как эта цитата выглядит. Для этого нужны архивные документы, которые к тому же  написаны не на современном языке. Вы привели два разных предложения. Согласен с тем, что двоеточие в предложении снимает вопрос. Но ведь гарантии нет, что и на этом ресурсе, где даже в заголовке пропущен мягкий знак в отчестве Суворова, приведена правильная цитата. Все перепечатывают, цензуры, профессиональной редактуры нет. Поэтому считаю, что оба варианта имеют право на жизнь. Вот например:. https://persona.rin.ru/cgi-bin/rus/view.pl?id=26187&a=f&idr=

Comment: Саша, по ссылке не пошла (ибо сомнений нет). Но понятно же, что это корректорская штучка с ручкой.

Comment: Ну да. Просто интересно, что на самом деле происходило: Суворов произнес, его слова передавались из уст в уста, или писарь тут же зафиксировал на бумаге, а потом какой-то издатель это вывел в свет... Докопаться ведь сложно.